# Java prepared statement get generated keys do not work in DB2 but work in mySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, db2

I have a very simple table that is in both MySQL and DB2 called `STUDENT`. The columns are: `ID` (primary key, auto incrementing), `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `AGE`.

The table is replicated in both databases, so they should be the same syntactically.

However, I have spent the entire day trying to figure out why, when I write a simple Java program to insert into the database, the MySQL version returns back the generated key via `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`, while the DB2 version does not return anything.

My code looks like:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Jacob', 'Eldy', 19)"

final Connection connection = getConnection(dataSource.get());

int[] insertedRows = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ps.addBatch();
    
    insertedRows = ps.executeBatch();

    rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
    
    while(rs.next()) {
        LOGGER.info(rs.getString(1));
    }
    connection.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        connection.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} finally {
    close(ps, connection);
}
```

After committing the connection for both databases DB2 and MySQL, both actually show the row being inserted, and the more I insert, a new row appears with an auto incremented `ID`, however only the MySQL database has a value in `while(rs.next())`, the DB2 version just skips over it since it is empty.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this just an incompatibility issue with DB2 and it just does not return the generated value? If so, what would be the best solution for tackling this issue?

UPDATE, adding the two DDLs for DB2 & mySQL:

mySQL DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE 'STUDENT'
  ...
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  PRIMARY KEY('ID')
  AUTO_INCREMENT=19073
```

DB2 DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
  ID INTEGER DEFAULT IDENTITY GENERATED ALWAYS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: Each DBMS have its own features which may absent or differ in the implementation in another DBMS. Both MySQL and DB2 have a function which returns the most last generated autoincrement value, it is LAST_INSERT_ID() in MySQL but IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() in DB2.

Comment: I have fixed two obvious issues in your `sql` string (unquoted string values, and missing close double quote), under the assumption that was a transcription issue. If that is not the case, then please make sure your code is a [mre] and actually compiles and executes as expected.

Comment: Exactly which DB2 are you using, and which DB2 driver (and version)? E.g. for _DB2 for z/OS_, see [Retrieving auto-generated keys for an INSERT statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=applications-retrieving-auto-generated-keys-insert-statement)

Comment: Also, please include the DDL of the table in DB2.

Comment: I think the problem might be in `executeBatch()` -- try it without batching, using `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: I have added the DDL, please let me know

Comment: @mustaccio I don't think there is a difference, but it is better for me to ```executeBatch()``` because there will be more than 1 insert for the table, and its better to insert in a batch rather then insert for every item in the list

Comment: You may think what you want, but did you at least try?

Comment: @stackerstack I've retrieved the generated keys for many tables in DB2 Windows, Linux, and AIX. Try mustaccio's solution. This should work as expected. By the way, which edition of DB2 are you using? z/OS, iSeries, LUW?

Comment: @TheImpaler i'm not exactly sure, but I am on a macbook pro, so I assume its the z/OS IBM version?

Comment: @stackerstack Try running: `select service_level from sysibmadm.env_inst_info;`

Comment: @TheImpaler that gives me a SQL Code -204 error :(

Comment: @mustaccio But you are correct, doing a executeUpdate does retrieve the generatedKeys. Why is that though?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to ask the Db2 driver developers. I personally don't see the usefulness of returning generated IDs for a batch of statements, because you won't be able to attribute an ID to a particular statement in the batch, especially if any of the statements have failed.

Comment: The reason I do that is because I can use the inserted and generated primary key ids to do a select on those where ID = returned keys. This then lets me return the inserted objects as a json with new id showing.

Comment: Support for generated keys when executing batches is not required by the JDBC specification, specifically, the JDBC 4.3 specification, section 13.6 _Retrieving Auto Generated Values_ says _"It is implementation-defined as to whether `getGeneratedKeys` will return generated values after invoking the `executeBatch` method."_. It looks like IBM decided not to support it for DB2 (maybe they can't do it easily or performant).

Comment: Interestingly, [Making batch updates in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=sql-making-batch-updates-in-jdbc-applications) seems to suggest generated keys are available after batch execution with the non-standard method `DB2PreparedStatement.getDBGeneratedKeys` (which returns an array of result sets, presumably one for each set of parameters in the batch).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT 
(
  ID            INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR (20)
, LAST_NAME     VARCHAR (20)
, AGE           SMALLINT
);
```

The following code based on the [Making batch updates in JDBC applications](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sql-making-batch-updates-in-jdbc-applications) links (this one is for Db2 for LUW) provided by others works as expected with the table definition above:

```
          PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement
          ( 
            "INSERT INTO STUDENT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?)"
          , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
          );
          ps.setString (1, "Jacob"); 
          ps.setString (2, "Eldy");
          ps.setShort (3, (short) 19);
          ps.addBatch(); 
          ps.setString (1, "Jacob"); 
          ps.setString (2, "Eldy");
          ps.setShort (3, (short) 19);
          ps.addBatch();                                  

          int [] numUpdates = ps.executeBatch(); 

          for (int i=0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) 
            if (numUpdates[i] == Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO)
              System.out.println("Execution " + i + ": unknown number of rows updated");
            else
              System.out.println("Execution " + i + " successful: " + numUpdates[i] + " rows updated");
          ResultSet[] resultList = ((com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PreparedStatement) ps).getDBGeneratedKeys(); 
          if (resultList.length != 0) 
            for (int i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) 
            {
                while (resultList[i].next()) 
                  System.out.println("Automatically generated key value = " + resultList[i].getBigDecimal(1));
                resultList[i].close();
            }
          else
            System.out.println("Error retrieving automatically generated keys");
```

Answer (score -1):

> Am I doing something wrong? Is this just an incompatibility issue with DB2 and it just does not return the generated value? If so, what would be the best solution for tackling this issue?

Yes, you are doing wrong. It's not incompatibility issue, and it's not an issue. DB2 is different than MySQL. You can't handle both because you have incompatible DDL. Since no records are inserted into DB2 the value of the key is not available.

The solution to the issue is to create a trigger on insert a record to make sure the primary key is inserted into DB. If you are missing a key then select it from the sequence and substitute the value.

Now if identity is generated into DB2 like this

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
  ID INTEGER DEFAULT IDENTITY GENERATED ALWAYS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

So it will always return `getGeneratedKeys()`.

Comment: If it is important to support both databases, it would be better to remove autoincrement and create the id's in java code, so it will work in any DB.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer autoincrement is good for MySQL, but it's not available in DB2, so the sequence is used to get the next key.

Comment: I think you are making assumptions about the DDL that are not included in the question. The link I posted in a comment on the question suggests that (some) DB2 version do have identity columns, and do support retrieving generated keys.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, let them add wrong DDL to the question. I thought it is only the issue when a generated key is not returning.

Comment: @RomanC when you say "Since no records are inserted into DB2 the value of the key is not available." do you mean that it is not inserting a record into DB2 and therefore the key isn't incremented and generated? Because it actually DOES insert the record after the commit(), it's just that the ```getGeneratedKeys()``` returns nothing for the DB2

Comment: I have added the DDL, please let me know what you think

Comment: @RomanC DB2 implements both types of `IDENTITY` so it does implement the same functionality as MySQL.

Comment: @stackerstack It cannot insert a record  without a key...

Comment: @TheImpaler Now I see it, since OP has added DB2 DDL.